# Algoritmo em C para converter número arábico em número romano

Tags: c, string, algoritmo, int, conversão

Como fazer essa conversão?

Não precisa ser o algoritmo pronto, queria uma ajuda pelo menos na lógica.

Comment: O que é um número arábico? E um número romano? O que você já fez? Tente melhorar um pouco a sua pergunta...

Comment: Número arábico são os números que conhecemos (0,1,2,3,....).
E sim queria saber como converter em romano.
Não fiz nada, só pensei, mas não consegui chegar em nenhuma solução

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/pt-BR/18484a71-f6bb-457a-b3fc-cf55fb7e1b3b/transformar-inteiroes-em-algarismos-romanos-em-c- aqui tem um exemplo ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    for (int i = 1; i < 3000; i++) {
        int numero = i;
        char *romanos[] = {"I", "IV", "V", "IX", "X", "XL", "L", "XC", "C", "CD", "D", "CM", "M"};
        int arabicos[] = {1, 4, 5, 9, 10, 40, 50, 90, 100, 400, 500, 900, 1000};
        // acha a quantidade de elementos no array
        int indice = (sizeof(arabicos) / sizeof(arabicos[0])) - 1;
        while (numero > 0) {
            if (numero >= arabicos[indice]) {
                printf("%s", romanos[indice]);
                numero -= arabicos[indice];
            } else {
                indice--;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/ctY4Yq). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kqnuopow-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/RomanNumbers.c).

Para fazer a conversão de números de 5000 (há controvérsias sobre o 4000 já exigir o "travessão superior") para cima complica porque precisa utilizar 2 linhas ou caracteres Unicode. Adapte para o jeito que acha melhor e atende sua necessidade.

Comment: Tem 11 votos à favor, a aceitação do AP, tem um *Demo* funcionando. Queria entender qual é o problema encontrado na resposta para ter 2 negativos.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ArabicToRoman (unsigned int numero, char *resultado) 
{
    char *centenas[] = {"", "C", "CC", "CCC", "CD", "D", "DC", "DCC", "DCCC", "CM"};
    char *dezenas[]  = {"", "X", "XX", "XXX", "XL", "L", "LX", "LXX", "LXXX", "XC"};
    char *unidades[] = {"", "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX"};
    int   size[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2,};

    while (numero >= 1000)
    {
        *resultado++ = 'M';
         numero -= 1000;
    }

    strcpy (resultado, centenas[numero / 100]); resultado += size[numero / 100]; numero = numero % 100;
    strcpy (resultado, dezenas[numero / 10]);   resultado += size[numero / 10];  numero = numero % 10;
    strcpy (resultado, unidades[numero]);       resultado += size[numero];
}

int main()
{
    char *romanNumber = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024);
    int numero;

    puts("Digite um valor a ser convertido: ");
    scanf("%d", &numero);

    ArabicToRoman(numero, romanNumber);
    printf("O valor %d equivale %s em romano\n", numero, romanNumber);

    return 0;
}
```

Por exemplo, pegue um caso em que o número a ser convertido para [numeração romana](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_romana)  é *635*. Bom, `numero / 100` resultará em *6*, nesse caso, o conjunto de pesquisa é `centenas`, *6* equivale a `DC`.

Em seguida `numero = numero % 100` resultará em *35*, então o conjunto de pesquisa será `dezenas`. `numero / 10` resultará em *3* que resultará `XXX`, depois em `numero = numero % 10` resultará *5*, onde o conjunto de pesquisa é `unidades` que dará o resultado `V`.

Sendo assim, o resultado final é `DCXXXV`.

- [**IdeOne**](https://ideone.com/vmn5HB)

Exemplo retirado [`daqui`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4986630/1608936).

Comment: Você percebeu que está jogando a string na sujeira da memória por causa da não alocação de `foo`?

Comment: Resposta muito boa, obrigado, me ajudou muito!